# What's the exact behavior of Flink continuous query?

Tags: apache-flink

I have two event sources from Kafka, one is from `user` topic, and the other is `order` topic,events from these two topics are created as Flink dynamic tables in my code.

I have following simple join query that want to calculate the order count placed by each user.

`select user_id,count(order_id) from user join order on user.user_id = order.user_id`,

I have following questions:

Assumes there is no data in users and orders when the application starts to run

1. Will the query task run immediately when Flink Kakfa connectors gets new data from the Kafka topic? How many events will be incldued in the query? eg, I wrote 1000 users and orders in one time from the Kafka console .
2. If the query(join or complex query) takes some time to finish ,say 1 minute, but new data from kafka is coming very frequent , will Flink first finish the previous round query and then run the next round query for the newly come data?
3. Flink spends much more time on query than receiving data from Kafka, how will Flink handle this speed mismatch? backpressure?
4. Can I control how often Flink reads Kafka data? eg, Flink Kafka connector reads Kafka for new data every 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to read up on https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/concepts/dynamic_tables/ and the other documentation on the Streaming Concepts in Flink.

In your case, it appears that you have two unbounded/streaming topics. That means that the end-result for your query is never finished and will be updated every time that new data is arriving on Kafka. It also means that everything needs to be kept in state, because there could be new data arriving that allows the result of the join needing to be updated.